# user registration validation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-form-builder

After entering data and try to register, the data is not updating in database.

```
  child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            final form = _formKey.currentState;
            if (form != null && !form.validate()) {
              save();
            } else {
              print("not ok");
            }
          },
          child: Text(
            "REGISTER",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
```

I am getting the "not ok" message in debug console

FULL CODE

```
    import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './user.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => InitState();
}

class InitState extends State<SignUpScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool isHiddenPassword = true;
  List<String> items = ['Select one', 'User', 'Collector'];
  String? selectedItem = 'Select one';
  User user = User('', '', '', '');
  Future save() async {
    try {
      var response = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://localhost:5000/user"),
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Context-Type': 'application/json;charSet=UTF-8'
          },
          body: <String, String>{
            // 'role': user.role,
            'name': user.name,
            'email': user.email,
            'phone': user.phone,
            'password': user.password
          });
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
        print(data['token']);
        print("account created succesfully");
      } else {
        print('failed');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    // .then((response) => print(response.body))
    // .catchError((err) => print(err));
    // print(res.body);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => initWidget();

  Widget initWidget() {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 250,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(90)),
            color: new Color(0xff1FAB89),
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [(new Color(0xff1FAB89)), new Color(0xff62D2A2)],
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
              child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/logoo.png',
                  height: 130,
                  width: 130,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, top: 20),
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                child: Text(
                  "Register",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )),
        ),
        Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 40),
            child: SizedBox(
                width: 200,
                child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(width: 3, color: Color(0xff1FAB89)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  value: selectedItem,
                  items: items
                      .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: item,
                            child: Text(item, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                  onChanged: (item) => setState(() => selectedItem = item),
                ))),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 40),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
          height: 54,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            color: Colors.grey[200],
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  offset: Offset(0, 10),
                  blurRadius: 50,
                  color: Color(0xffEEEEEE)),
            ],
          ),
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: TextEditingController(text: user.name),
            onChanged: (value) {
              user.name = value;
            },
            validator: (value) {
              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                return "Enter Something";
              } else {
                return null;
              }
            },
            cursorColor: Color(0xff1FAB89),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Color(0xff1FAB89),
              ),
              hintText: "Full Name",
              enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
              focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 20),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
          height: 54,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            color: Colors.grey[200],
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  offset: Offset(0, 10),
                  blurRadius: 50,
                  color: Color(0xffEEEEEE)),
            ],
          ),
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: TextEditingController(text: user.email),
            onChanged: (value) {
              user.email = value;
            },
            validator: (value) {
              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                return "Enter Something";
              } else if (RegExp(
                      r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
                  .hasMatch(value)) {
                return null;
              } else {
                return "enter valid email";
              }
            },
            cursorColor: Color(0xff1FAB89),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.email,
                color: Color(0xff1FAB89),
              ),
              hintText: "Email",
              enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
              focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 20),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
          height: 54,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            color: Color(0xffEEEEEE),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  offset: Offset(0, 20),
                  blurRadius: 100,
                  color: Color(0xffEEEEEE)),
            ],
          ),
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: TextEditingController(text: user.phone),
            onChanged: (value) {
              user.phone = value;
            },
            validator: (value) {
              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                return "Enter Something";
              } else {
                return null;
              }
            },
            cursorColor: Color(0xff1FAB89),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              focusColor: Color(0xff1FAB89),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.phone,
                color: Color(0xff1FAB89),
              ),
              hintText: "Phone Number",
              enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
              focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 20),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
          height: 54,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            color: Color(0xffEEEEEE),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                  offset: Offset(0, 20),
                  blurRadius: 100,
                  color: Color(0xffEEEEEE)),
            ],
          ),
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: TextEditingController(text: user.password),
            onChanged: (value) {
              user.password = value;
            },
            validator: (value) {
              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                return "Enter Something";
              } else {
                return null;
              }
            },
            obscureText: isHiddenPassword,
            cursorColor: Color(0xff1FAB89),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              focusColor: Color(0xff1FAB89),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.vpn_key,
                color: Color(0xff1FAB89),
              ),
              hintText: "Enter Password",
              suffixIcon: InkWell(
                onTap: _togglePasswordView,
                child: Icon(
                  isHiddenPassword ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
                  color: Color(0xff1FAB89),
                ),
              ),
              enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
              focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 50),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
            height: 54,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [(new Color(0xff1FAB89)), new Color(0xff62D2A2)],
                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  end: Alignment.centerRight),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              color: Colors.grey[200],
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    offset: Offset(0, 10),
                    blurRadius: 50,
                    color: Color(0xffEEEEEE)),
              ],
            ),
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final form = _formKey.currentState;
                if (form != null && form.validate()) {
                  save();
                } else {
                  print("not ok");
                }
              },
              child: Text(
                "REGISTER",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text("Have An Account?  "),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Text(
                  "Login Now",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff1FAB89)),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  // Write Tap Code Here.
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    )));
  }

  void _togglePasswordView() {
    setState(() {
      isHiddenPassword = !isHiddenPassword;
    });
  }
}
```

THE CODE WHERE I USE THIS VALIDATOR

```dart
GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 50),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
        height: 54,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [(new Color(0xff1FAB89)), new Color(0xff62D2A2)],
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          color: Colors.grey[200],
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                offset: Offset(0, 10),
                blurRadius: 50,
                color: Color(0xffEEEEEE)),
          ],
        ),
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            final form = _formKey.currentState;
            if (form != null && form.validate()) {
              save();
            } else {
              print("not ok");
            }
          },
          child: Text(
            "REGISTER",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

These is the code
the last piece of code is taken from the main code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added ! Before form.validate() which means only if it fails it will save. Remove the ! Mark before form.validate(). The code should be like this

```
if(form != null && form.validate()) {
              save();
            } else {
              print("not ok");
            }
```

In your form widget add this key

```
SingleChildScrollView (
 child : Form(
key : _formKey,
 child: Column(
  children: [
   //Textfield and buttons here
  ]
 )
 )
}
```

Comment: done that and run the code. but the same Result.
Is there any other option

Comment: Did you assign the _formKey to the Form widget?

Comment: yes done that......
class InitState extends State<SignUpScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

Comment: No i mean in the form... edited my answer

Comment: yes i done it , in the way u suggested

Comment: Can you paste the full code in question?

Comment: Did it work as expected?

Comment: i post full code

Comment: sorry for the delay

Comment: the last code the piece of code which is taken from the above full code

Comment: i dont know how to add key
can u please add it to my code

Comment: Wrap the column which is inside the SingleChildScrollView with a Form widget. Add key to the form like in my answer

Comment: return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          Form(
            key : _formKey,
            child: Column(
      children: [

Comment: is it like this
i think there is mistake, its showing errors

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: i will add a picture with my question

Comment: i cant get a edit option

Comment: Paste the error in comments

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LKjo73Lop6LkBd9jhk0hP9fr5hPMhdxj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can u refer this image

Comment: You missed child: before Form

Comment: : Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
lib/signup_screen.dart:50
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
                                   ^
/C:/app/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/single_child_scroll_view.dart:140:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const SingleChildScrollView({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: so where i need to add child?

Comment: Inside SingleChildScrollView you added form without the key 'child:'. Just add child: before Form.

Comment: the error is gone

Comment: so, why we need to add child there?? my doubt..

Comment: Form is the child of SingleChildScrollView

Comment: I/flutter (20697): SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 36136

Comment: Now your save method is called

Comment: this is the console log now showing

Comment: Consider using a chat room

Comment: yeah it worked , now this is showing

Comment: can i connect u in twitter?

Comment: Yeasin it isn't showing up on my phone bro. Trying to get it from a long time now lol

Comment: What i need to do next?

Comment: http://localhost:5000/user doesn't seem like the correct url unless you have it hosted locally.

Comment: so how i host it locally?

Comment: Please mark it add an answer if it worked. For other questions please add a new question in SO

Comment: In postman this is working correctly

Comment: i cant add question after 90 minutes

Comment: can i connect with you somewhere else?

Comment: Yeah but it's better in SO. So you get better answers from a lot of experienced developers

Comment: yeah i will also try that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73030822/user-registration-using-flutter-and-node-js

Comment: New question @KaushikChandru

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73100093/getlocation-function-giving-a-static-access-error    new error