# getLocation() function giving a static access error

Tags: flutter, google-maps, visual-studio-code, static, project

The **getLocation()** function showing error.

The **error** is : Instance member 'getLocation' can't be accessed using static access.

Also i added polylines, it is also dont showing in the app. The polylines showing no error, but it is not visible in the map, which is inside the app.

The code is:

```
    import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_polyline_points/flutter_polyline_points.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
// import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';

// import 'package:latlng/latlng.dart';
String googleApiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";

class Maps extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => InitState();
}

class InitState extends State<Maps> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  static const LatLng sourcelocation = LatLng(9.6265, 76.7755);
  static const LatLng destination = LatLng(9.6361, 76.7769);

  List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];
  LocationData? currentLocation;

  void getCurrentLocation() {
    Location location = Location();
    
    Location.getLocation().then(
      (location) {
        currentLocation = location;
      },
    );
  }

  void getPolyPoints() async {
    PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();

    PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
      googleApiKey,
      PointLatLng(sourcelocation.latitude, sourcelocation.longitude),
      PointLatLng(destination.latitude, destination.longitude),
    );
    if (result.points.isNotEmpty) {
      result.points.forEach(
        (PointLatLng point) => polylineCoordinates.add(
          LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude),
        ),
      );
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getCurrentLocation();
    getPolyPoints();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => initWidget();

  Widget initWidget() {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          backgroundColor: new Color(0xff1FAB89),
          elevation: 10.0,
          toolbarHeight: 50,
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text("Map"),
              Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0))
            ],
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(14))),
        ),
        // body: Column(
        //     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        //     children: <Widget>[
        //       Container(
        //           height: 600.0,
        //           width: double.infinity,
        //           child: GoogleMap(
        //               onMapCreated: (controller) {
        //                 setState(() {
        //                   myController = controller;
        //                 });
        //               },
        //               compassEnabled: true,
        //               initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        //                   target: latlng(9.6265, 76.7755), zoom: 15.0)))
        //     ]),
        body: currentLocation == null
            ? const Center(child: Text("Loading"))
            : GoogleMap(
                mapType: MapType.normal,
                myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: LatLng(currentLocation!.latitude!,
                        currentLocation!.longitude!),
                    zoom: 14.5),
                polylines: {
                    Polyline(
                      polylineId: PolylineId('route'),
                      points: polylineCoordinates,
                      color: Color(0xFF4285F4),
                      width: 6,
                    ),
                  },
                markers: {
                    Marker(
                      markerId: const MarkerId("Current Location"),
                      position: LatLng(currentLocation!.latitude!,
                          currentLocation!.longitude!),
                    ),
                    const Marker(
                      markerId: MarkerId("Source"),
                      position: sourcelocation,
                    ),
                    const Marker(
                      markerId: MarkerId("Destination"),
                      position: destination,
                    )
                  }));
  }
}
```

[The image of error getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AelfH.png)

Comment: I've removed the API key from the post for security and privacy concerns. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a typo in `Location.getLocation()`. It should be a lowercase `l` instead of the uppercase `L`.

Instead of this

```dart
  void getCurrentLocation() {
    Location location = Location();
    
    Location.getLocation().then(     // <- There is a typo here
      (location) {
        currentLocation = location;
      },
    );
  }
```

Do this:

```dart
  void getCurrentLocation() {
    Location location = Location();
    
    location.getLocation().then(     // <- Fixed here
      (location) {
        currentLocation = location;
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Why my polylines is not showing?

Comment: use this inside init state - WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      getPolyPoints();
    });

Comment: No it is not showing

Comment: Also the marker id is also not showing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SiME1v4PQWIZb6Cfuq9u7ABiQIw4s2Ac/view?usp=sharing

Comment: im getting an exception like in the pic i mentioned above

Comment: @lepsch Why this happen, please help

Comment: the check `currentLocation == null ? const Center(child: Text("Loading")) : GoogleMap(...` from the screenshot. Just add it back

Comment: but i add that, the map is not loading

Comment: only the white page with "Loading" is showing

Comment: @lepsch is there anyother way

Comment: you are getting null value in currentLocation..... getCurrentLocation should be async method also await before location.getLocation()

Comment: You should call the `getCurrentLocation();` in the `initState`. Just uncomment it out.

Comment: but i need to done a hot reload by using ctrl+s

Comment: to show the map

Comment: @lepsch thats a mistake in the question , i done that early

Comment: @lepsch i need to use ctrl+ s to load the map, otherwise it is showing "loading"

Comment: You should call `setState(() => currentLocation = location);` instead of just `currentLocation = location;` in `getCurrentLocation` function

Comment: why is the marker id like source, destination is not showing in marker

Comment: @lepsch do u have any solution for that

Comment: I'm not sure. Did you follow the required set-up [here](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)?

Comment: done that already